# Can a self-containing set be used to define natural numbers?

Tags: set-theory

I was wondering now (trying to escape from Santa and Jesus at this Christmas Eve) if the existence, in $\mathsf{ZF}-$(Infinity$+$Regularity), of a set $x$ such that $x=\{x\}$, can be used in some way to prove the existence of a minimal $\in$-inductive set.

My motivation? well... for a such set $x$ we have $x=\{x\}=\bigl\{\{x\}\bigr\}=\Bigl\{\bigl\{\{x\}\bigr\}\Bigr\}=\cdots$, and I would like to exploit this to decodify and collect, in some set, the number of pairs of braces.

Comment: Incidentally, such sets are called *Quine atoms*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is consistent with ZF-Inf-Reg that there are *two* sets $a$ and $b$ with $a\not=b$ but $a=\{a\}$ and $b=\{b\}$. Each is an inductive set, and neither contains the other; so in such a model there is no minimal inductive set.

In particular, this means that the existence of a Quine atom in the first place cannot imply the existence of a minimal inductive set.

Meanwhile, I have no idea how to use a Quine atom in the way you outline; maybe you can be a bit more specific? How exactly do you intend to use a Quine atom for a "decoding" process?

Comment: That's a very beautiful and very weird result. Do you have a reference to where I could read more on it?

Comment: @Mingus I don't know a specific reference, but any model of ZFA (= ZF with atoms) can be turned into a model of ZF without Foundation, in which each of the former atoms is now a Quine atom. So starting with a model of ZFA with more than one atom, you get a model of ZF minus Foundation with more than one Quine atom. Similarly for ZF-Inf. (Incidentally, while Aczel's AntiFoundation Axiom implies that there's *exactly one* Quine atom, Boffa's AFA implies that there are many.)

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be akin to Zermelo's definition of the integers: $0=\varnothing; n+1=\{n\}$. Of course, we can still define the set $\Bbb N$ as all the sets defined for the natural numbers. However this set will not be the limit, in any reasonable set-theoretic sense, of the natural numbers themselves.

This is why von Neumann's construction of the ordinals is superior.

But let me add two things to Noah's answer here:

1. An inductive set also has $\varnothing$ as an element. And the reason is exactly because we want to ensure that there is a set which is closed under the definable function $x\mapsto x\cup\{x\}$, *and* that this function is injective but not surjective. This is not the case with Quine atoms. So you might want to talk about a different type of "inductive" here.
2. It is impossible to use a Quine atom to define the natural numbers. Easily we can prove by induction that since $x=\{x\}$, it follows that $\{\ldots\{x\}\ldots\}=x$ again for any finite number of applications of the singleton operation. So using $x$ instead of $0$ to model the natural numbers would result in $0=1=2=3=\ldots$ and the core idea that $0\neq 1$ will be false now.

   Note that this would also be the case if we take the von Neumann reinterpretation: $0=x, n+1=n\cup\{n\}$; as in this case we can also prove by induction that $n=n+1=x$, since $x=\{x\}$. So trying with a Quine atom but a different direction might not be useful either.

So even if Quine atoms do exist, they do not interfere with the *standard* definition of inductive sets, and they are not useful for defining the natural numbers in a simple set theoretic way.

Comment: To the O.P. : In the absence of Infinity we cannot expect to prove the existence of a SET of natural numbers.  But we may define (without Inf and without Reg) $x\in On$ iff ($x$ is transitive and is well-ordered by $\epsilon$.) (...A set  $x$ is transitive iff  $\forall y\in x \;(y \subset x)$...).  We may then define $x\in \omega \iff $ $(x\in On \land \forall y\in x\cup \{x\}\;(y=\cup y\implies y=\emptyset)).$